# C# SqlDataReader: Receive all affected Rows from Transaction

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I was wondering how to receive the affected rows from Queries inside a MSSQL- / TSQL-TRANSACTION that is executed by a C#-Script with a SqlConnection, SqlCommand and a SqlDataReader. 
Does anybody knows how to get it?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Do you want the actual rows themselves or the _number_ of rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ExecuteNonQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) method of a `SqlCommand` object returns the number of rows affected.

Comment: Sorry, my formulation was a little bit tricky, I meant that I send a full TRANSACTION with some queries (more than 1) and I want to receive each affected row from each query inside the TRANSACTION

Comment: @TobiasRaphaelDieckmann you will get the combined number i guess. If you want indidual numbers, you need to execute it separately.

Comment: Thanks Shyju, that are awefull news, is there an easy way to interpretate and seperate each of the queries inside the transaction or do I have to do it by myself?